# how to pass two variable values from a java util list class

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Please, i'm trying to pass two values "ID" and "Name" from a class
but i've only managed to retrieve the name and i'm finding it difficult to get the ID. this is the code

```
private void getStates()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    final String token = sharedPreferences.getString("auth", "");

    RetrofitClient retrofitClient = new RetrofitClient();
    ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofitClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<StateResponse> call = apiInterface.getState("Bearer "+token);
    //Log.d("debug", call.request().headers().toString());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<StateResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<StateResponse> call, Response<StateResponse> response) {
            Log.d("debug", response.body().toString());
            Log.d("TAG", "onResponse: yipeeeeeee "+response.body().getAllstates() +""+token+"");
            List<StateData> data = response.body().getAllstates();
            String[] mState = new String[data.size()];


            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
            {
                mState[i] = data.get(i).getStateName();
            }


            ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mState);
            spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            state.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

            String STATE = state.getSelectedItem().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<StateResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            ProgressDialogLoader.progressdialog_dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(InsertActivity.this, "Couldn't Add", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

i need the ID of the selected spinner item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
            String id= yourIdArray.get(pos);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Create a separate array which stores all id as same sequence as name now when you select any item from spinner `onItemSelected` method will be called it gives you position, that position will give you id via  `String id= yourIdArray.get(pos);`

Comment: How do i create the array, cuz i can only get one variable which is the getName

Comment: I supposed that you have id for each state, if its is not then which id you are talking about in question?

Answer (score 0):

Delcler global instans of **StateResponse**

```
StateResponse stateResponse;
int id;
```

then implements OnItemSelectedListener

```
state.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    switch (parent.getId()) {

        case R.id.state:

           id=stateResponse.get(position).getId();

            break;

    }
}
```

Then in Retrofit Callback

```
stateResponse=response.body();
```